# Modifying probability of selection in PySpark sampling without replacement

Tags: python, r, random, pyspark, sampling

I understand that to sample efficiently, Spark uses Bernouilli Sampling where it allocates each row in the sample the same probability of being included.

I would like to know if there is a way of sampling in PySpark modifying this probability of selection, to say, a mantissa, instead of each row having the same probability of being selected.

Thank you for your response. Please see below for Python code that I am using to sample nsize amount of rows using the sample method.

sampleout_lsoa['nsize'] = sampleout_lsoa['*nsize*'].astype(int)

```
sample_lsoa = (sampleout_lsoa.groupby(stratum_lsoa, group_keys = False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(x['nsize'].iloc[0])))
```

stratum_lsoa are a list of stratum that I am sampling on. nsize are a column of integer value representing the number of rows, per strata that I require to be sampled.

At the moment I believe that Python allocates each row an even chance of being selected; so if nsize respresented a 10% sample of the rows in the DataFrame sampleout_lsoa, each row will have a 10% chance of being included.

What I would like is a way of altering this probability of selection to values between 0.0 and 1.0; a different decimal for each row so that determines its chance of being selected. Do you know if this is possible in Python,R or Spark?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit with code sample and example of what do you  want?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please see above for code plus further information.